# I need to sum numbers in a file

Tags: python

Ok I'm learning read and write files at the moment but I need a little help to sum the numbers in a file.

```
def main ():
    sample = open (r'C:\user\desktop\text.txt','r')
    for i in range (the range of int is unknown)
        file = sample.read ()
    sample.close ()
main ()
```

Comment: you can only call `sample.read()` one time ... then the pointer is at the end of the file ...

Comment: What part of summing do you not understand? Do you know how to initialize a variable to zero and then use the + operator with assignment? Is it reading integers from the file that has you tripped up? What does the data in the file look like?

Comment: `sum(map(int,sample.read().split()))`

Comment: @scrappedcola I think it's quite clear that what he really doesn't understand is how to read a file.

Comment: How many numbers per line?

Comment: @AlexHall no actually it's rather ambiguous. It looks like all he needs is how to read the file but he is actually asking "i need a little help to sum the numbers" not "I don't seem able to read an integer from the file".This question is low quality and these are details that should have been there without prompting.

Answer (score 2):

You may iterate over the file like this:

```
for i in sample:
```

and convert using `int()` to an integer.

The `for` loop can be done with map and the sum with `sum`.

This is the final code:

```
def main ():
    sample = open (r'C:\user\desktop\text.txt','r')
    result = sum(map(int, sample))
    print(result)
    sample.close ()
main ()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
for line in sample:
    # process the line
```

If each line just contains an integer, you can simplify it further to `sum(map(int, sample))`.

Answer (score 0):

To add safety, you should cast your integers with error checking and ensure that the file exists before reading it.

```
import os

def safecast(newtype, val, default=None):
    try:
        return newtype(val)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return default

def sumfile(filename):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return None
    sum = 0
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            sum += safecast(int, line, 0)
    return sum

sum = sumfile(r'C:\user\desktop\text.txt')
print(sum)
```